# Extending viewpager with navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, android-viewpager, drawer

At the moment I have a Base Activity class which implements an action bar across all my activities, I now want to add to this base class so that it implements a navigation drawer. But having a base activity which implements a navigation drawer gives me a lot of conflicting view errors.

My main goal is to have a viewpager activity extend this base activity which implements a navigation drawer, How can I do this? or is there a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing this. I don't exactly remember where I took it but it is also changed. In my case I defined it as abstract and extended my MainActivity from this. The reason was to keep the logic related to DrawerActivity in one class so it is not mixed with my business logic.

```
public abstract class DrawerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerListener;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListAdapter mDrawerListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportContentChanged() {
        super.onSupportContentChanged();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (mDrawerLayout == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Your layout must be a DrawerLayout"
            );
        }
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        if (mDrawerList == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Your content must have a ListView"
            );
        }


        mDrawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                onDrawerClose(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                onDrawerOpen(drawerView);
            }

        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerListAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerListener.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ensureDrawerList();
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null));
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_activity, null);
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        layout.addView(view);
        super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
    }

    public void onDrawerToggle() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    public void setDrawerListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureDrawerList();
            mDrawerListAdapter = adapter;
        }
    }

    public void setDrawerListSelection(int position) {
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    public int getSelectedDrawerItemPosition() {
        return mDrawerList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    public long getSelectedDrawerItemId() {
        return mDrawerList.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    protected void onDrawerClose(View view) {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    protected void onDrawerOpen(View drawerView) {
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            onListItemClick((ListView) parent, v, position, id);
        }
    };

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    }

    private void ensureDrawerList() {
        if (mDrawerList != null) {
            return;
        }
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    }

    public ListView getDrawerList() {
        return mDrawerList;
    }
}
```

drawer_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. I did something like this before without declaring it abstract but it resulted in the Main Activity overriding the navigation drawer with its setContentView.

Comment: This isn't what I am looking I don't think, I think you are still referring to using fragments to fill the views. I am looking specifically to extend the navigation drawer activity with another activity

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and i just fixed it tonight.

I had a view pager/swipe tab setup that i wanted to add a navigation drawer to.

I built my navigation drawer to extend to my view pager according to [this](http://androiddeveloperdemo.blogspot.com/2014/08/android-navigation-drawer-with-multiple.html) tutorial.
when i tried to extend it to my viewpager class i had to remove the "fragmentactivity" extend for "navigator". this gave me the same issue your having now. it took me 3 hours of research to realize that if i extend class A in class B, then as long as class A is "Extending" the same "supporting Class" that Class B needs, then you wont have that null pointer issue.

here the code: navigation_draw.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

android java:

```
package com.navigation.drawer.activity;
/**
* @author dipenp
*
* This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to      navigation drawer.
* We are going to extend all our other activites from this BaseActivity so that every activity will        have Navigation Drawer in it.
* This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.   
*/
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

/**
 *  Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
 *  This layout is protected so that child activity can access this 
 *  */
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

/**
 * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
 * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened. 
 */

protected ListView mDrawerList;

/**
 * List item array for navigation drawer items.
 * */
protected String[] listArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };

/**
 * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list. 
 * */
protected static int position;

/**
 *  This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time
 *  so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.   
 * */
private static boolean isLaunch = true;

/**
 *  Base layout node of this Activity.   
 * */
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

/**
 * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            openActivity(position);
        }
    });

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                       /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    /**
     * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
     * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
     * */
    if(isLaunch){
         /**
          *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
          *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity.
          *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
          */
        isLaunch = false;
        openActivity(0);
    }
}

/**
 * @param position
 *
 * Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
 */
protected void openActivity(int position) {

    /**
     * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
     * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
     * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
     * So that we are setting this in child activity.   
     */

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Item1Activity.class));
        break;
    case 1:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Item2Activity.class));
        break;
    case 2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Item3Activity.class));
        break;
    case 3:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Item4Activity.class));
        break;
    case 4:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Item5Activity.class));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
}
```

my pager adapter code (notice this pager class extends only the navigator, and the navigator extends activity...this will not work (your issue) if you change the "extends activity" in Navigator to "extends FragmentActivity" the pager and drawer will work. Because this view pager uses FragmentActivity):

```
public class StartActive extends Navigator implements TabListener
{
MyAdapter adapt;
ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager viewPager = null;
String userName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_active);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_start_active, frameLayout);

    naviList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(category[position]);
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        userName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME);
    }


    swipeTabs();    

}



public void swipeTabs()
{

    FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    adapt = new MyAdapter(fragMan);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.startActive_Activity);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapt);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) 
        {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
        {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
        {


        }
    });
    android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("User");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Maps");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Feed");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start_active, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
{

    public PlaceholderFragment() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_active, container, false);
        Log.d("Life cycles", "onCreateView");
        return rootView;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) 
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) 
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) 
{

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME, userName);
        Fragment frag;
        switch(arg0)
        {
        case 1:
            return new GMaps();
        case 0:

            frag = new UserView();
            frag.setArguments(b);
            return frag;
        case 2:
            frag = new FeedView();
            frag.setArguments(b);
            return frag;
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return 3;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Navigation Drawer on top of the ViewPager here's what you can do:

**Incase if you don't know about the Navigationdrawer properly please check this link**([Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8hSIP2ha-g))
use this code within your relative Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/custom_drawer_layout">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
                <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText" />

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/notification_drawer_fragement"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:name="address to fragment class"
        tools:layout="@layout/notification_fragment"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is what you will get:

1 is the fragment and 2 is the viewPager
[image]